# vb.net runs gpg.exe step of job runs ok from PC but not from SQL Server Agent schedule

Tags: vb.net, filepath, gnupg, hidden-files, executable-path

Everything worked great from my Visual Studio on my PC running this from the Start button. When I build the executable and copied the executable to the production box and scheduled the job via SQL Server Agent on the production machine – everything worked fine to create the file, but the encryption bit does not work.
The gpg.exe is here on the production server:    \sql2014\c$\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin

The gpg is here on my PC:     C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin

The filename.csv gets created in the proper location ok - I tested with both these names
Dim Extract_File As String  = “\sql2014\e$\Extracts\ProgramName\filename.csv”
‘Dim Extract_File As String  = “E:\Extracts\ProgramName\filename.csv” ‘do to  this from my PC I had to change the E: to a C:

This line calls the function:
    FileEncrypted = Encrypt_File(Extract_File, Batch_Timestamp)

```
Private Function Encrypt_File(File_To_Encrypt As String, Batch_Timestamp As Date)
    On Error GoTo Encrypt_File_Error
    Dim Success As Boolean = False
    Dim sourceName As String = File_To_Encrypt
    Dim gpgProcess = New Process()
    ‘Test with working directory - no effect
    ‘gpgProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 
    'gpgProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "\\sql2014\c$\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\"
    ‘gpgProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "gpg.exe"
    gpgProcess.StartInfo.FileName = \\sql2014\c$\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe  ‘This works from my PC
    ‘gpgProcess.StartInfo.FileName = \\sql2014\c$\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bn\gpg.exe  ‘If I change this path took the “i” out of bin I get an error:  The system cannot find the file specified
    gpgProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 
    gpgProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    gpgProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--batch --yes --recipient reciptname --encrypt " & sourceName
    gpgProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    gpgProcess.Start()
    gpgProcess.WaitForExit()
    If FileExists(sourceName & ".gpg") Then
        Success = True
    End If
Encrypt_File_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    ‘gpgProcess.WaitForExit() moved this up to 
    gpgProcess.Close()
    Return Success
    Exit Function
Encrypt_File_Error:
    Error_Handler("SomeModule.vb", "Encrypt_File", Err, System_Output, Batch_Timestamp)
    Resume Encrypt_File_Exit
End Function
```

Any suggestions for how I can resolve this. When it worked on my PC it creates a filename.csv.gpg in the same directory as filename.csv. On the production server it does not create the gpg and it does not give a visible error message either.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue. I Installed the OpenPgpLib from the NuGet Package Manager and re-wrote this Function as shown here.
I created the .asc file from the Kleopatra tool and saved it in the location used in the pubkey in the code bit below. The OpenPgp is from the package.

```
    Private Function Encrypt_File(File_To_Encrypt As String, Log_File As String, Batch_Timestamp As Date)
        Dim Success As Boolean = False
        Dim encryptthis As String = File_To_Encrypt
        Dim thisencrypted As String = File_To_Encrypt & ".gpg"
        Dim pubkey As String = "\\sql2014\c$\Data_Programs\MyDirectory\<thepublickeyfile>.asc"
        Try
            OpenPgp.EncryptFile(encryptthis, thisencrypted, pubkey, False, False)
            If FileExists(thisencrypted) Then
                Success = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            App_Logger(Log_File, ex.StackTrace.ToString(), System_Output, Batch_Timestamp)
            Success = False
        End Try
        Return Success
    End Function
```